# ajax call: response <->data type

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I simply want to submit form data (JS) to php script.
I am using following code:

```
    form.children("div").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex){


            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":enabled,:hidden";
            return form.valid();
        },
        onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex){
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":enabled";;
            return form.valid();
            },
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex, name){
            var name = JSON.stringify($("#userName").val());
            var password =JSON.stringify( $("#password").val());

            $.ajax({
                url: "getInfo.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {username: name, password: password},
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#response').append(response);                        
                }

            });

        }
    });
```

The script "getInfo" receives the sent data "username" and password" and can perform further actions like db calls etc. Now I want to echo a table like:

**echo "table..[some data]..";**

But the correspondig div "response" remains empty..
If I change the **dataType** to "text", the **.append** actually appends something (although not correctly..) but now the webserver throws an error concerning a constant which is used somewhere else in the php script..

I think I am missing a basic thing here, but I really did not find a solution...

Comment: Changing the `dataType` can't have any effect on the server script. It doesn't send anything to the server, it just changes what jQuery does with the response.

Comment: The problem is in your PHP code. Post the code, and the exact error message.

Comment: There's no need to call `JSON.stringify` on the parameters. The data will be encoded using `x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Answer (score 0):

echo in json_encode(array()) in your "getInfo.php" because your datatype is json

Comment: Great thx, I always assumed "dataType" would actually have an impact on the server side.. The "error" I mentioned actually is a "Notice" from WAMPP: " Notice: Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a' in C:\wamp\www\getInfo.php on line 8" : $file_handle=fopen("log.txt",a);

Comment: The notice messages can be disabled in php.ini I found out.

Comment: ...but anywho... is this thre "right" way to continue working? I mean do I build sites likes this? Building some fancy guis in js, process the data using php and sendin the data back to js which "appends" the data to an actual html div?